# com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding in WebLogic Server

Tags: weblogic, datasource, target

I'm using `WebLogic Server` Version: `12.1.3.0.0` and when I try to set the target of my `DataSource` to the `AdminServer` the following error shows in the log:

```
<2020.08.25. 10:51:27 CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "71744041298900" for task "weblogic.deploy.configChangeTask.3". Error is: "com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding."
com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding.
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_SymmetricCipher.decryptFinal(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:124)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:187)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding.
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_SymmetricCipher.decryptFinal(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:124)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:187)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<2020.08.25. 10:51:27 CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating activate task for application "MyDS".> 
<2020.08.25. 10:51:27 CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding.
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_SymmetricCipher.decryptFinal(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:124)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:187)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_PaddingException: Invalid padding.
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_SymmetricCipher.decryptFinal(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptBytes(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:124)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.decryptString(JSafeEncryptionServiceImpl.java:187)
    at weblogic.security.internal.encryption.ClearOrEncryptedService.decrypt(ClearOrEncryptedService.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

When I've created the `DataSource` the testing of the connection run successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataSource` xml in the `user_projects\domains\base_domain_new\config\jdbc\` directory may be imported. In this case You have to clear out the `Password` and the `Confirm Password` fields in the `DataSource`'s `Configuration\Connection Pool` tab and hit `Save` then type the password in once again.